# get a break meaning

Tags: meaning

I often hear this usage of "break" in criminal documentaries and I don't know what it means exactly. Here's an example:

> In the house, police **get another break** when they find Kacie's
>   discarded note.

I checked all of the meaning of "break", the closest meaning was:

> An often sudden piece of luck, especially good luck: finally got the
>   big break in life.

So does it mean like police got lucky when they found the note? It sounds more like clue by looking at context "get another clue" but I don't know.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means.

Comment: Yep, "get a break" means, roughly, "have a piece of good luck".  Note that there are several other meanings of "break", but in the context of "get a break" the meaning is reasonably unambiguous.

Comment: @HotLicks In this particular case, it might be the *break* of "*break in the case*": an essential clue or piece of evidence which opens avenues of investigation previously hidden or inaccessible.

Comment: @DanBron - I would guess there are several idioms derived from the meaning "to disrupt the order or compactness of" (which is one of about 40 meanings Merriam-Webster lists).  The "break" in "get a break" and "break in the case" then comes from a change in the (presumably less than ideal) routine sequence of events up to that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all

**break = favorable opportunity**

Now for the meaning: search Google Books with:

**"get a break" idiom**

and you'll get many idiom dictionaries explaining it. Drill down into one of them:

> get a break
>
> **Obtain a favorable opportunity; get special consideration or treatment**.
>
> For example,
>
> *The understudy finally got a break when the star became ill*,
>
> or
>
> *The new price is higher, but you are getting a break on service*.
>
> The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms, Second Edition - Page 163
>   Christine Ammer - 2013

Comment: Thanks. As a non-native speaker aware of the meaning of "giving a break", I always thought that getting a break meant, you know, that someone *actually* gave you a break.